# Run code after Hibernate updates database schema?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, orm

Is there a way to register some kind of SchemaExportEventListener (that's a name I've chosen) with Hibernate, so that after it has generated the DDL we can make some updates (which Hibernate doesn't support) to the database?

We need to set a case-insensitive unique constraint on a PostgreSQL column, and while this is perfectly possible in PostgreSQL, it doesn't seem possible within Hibernate/JPA annotations (neither `@Table(uniqueConstraint)` nor `@Column(columnDefinition)` nor `@Column(unique)` quite do what we want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to register some kind of SchemaExportEventListener (that's a name I've chosen) with Hibernate

To my knowledge, Hibernate doesn't have anything like that.

> so that after it has generated the DDL we can make some updates (which Hibernate doesn't support) to the database?

However, the `import.sql` feature might help here. With Hibernate, you can put an `import.sql` file on the root of the classpath and it will get executed after the schema generation (assuming you're using either `create` or `create-drop`). Quoting the [Rotterdam JBug and Hibernate's import.sql](http://relation.to/9081.lace) blog post:

> #### [import.sql: easily import data in your unit tests](http://relation.to/Bloggers/RotterdamJBugAndHibernatesImportsql#H-ImportsqlEasilyImportDataInYourUnitTests)
>
> Hibernate has a neat little feature
>   that is heavily under-documented and
>   unknown. You can execute an SQL script
>   during the `SessionFactory` creation
>   right after the database schema
>   generation to import data in a fresh
>   database. You just need to add a file
>   named `import.sql` in your classpath
>   root and set either `create` or
>   `create-drop` as your
>   `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property.
>
> I use it for Hibernate Search in
>   Action now that I have started the
>   query chapter. It initializes my
>   database with a fresh set of data for
>   my unit tests. JBoss Seam also uses it
>   a lot in the various examples.
>   `import.sql` is a very simple feature
>   but is quite useful at time. Remember
>   that the SQL might be dependent on
>   your database (ah portability!).
>
> ```
> #import.sql file
> delete from PRODUCTS
> insert into PRODUCTS (PROD_ID, ASIN, TITLE, PRICE, IMAGE_URL, DESCRIPTION) values ('1', '630522577X', 'My Fair Lady', 19.98, '630522577X.jpg', 'My Fair blah blah...');
> insert into PRODUCTS (PROD_ID, ASIN, TITLE, PRICE, IMAGE_URL, DESCRIPTION) values ('2', 'B00003CXCD', 'Roman Holiday ', 12.98, 'B00003CXCD.jpg', 'We could argue that blah blah');
> ```
>
> For more information about this
>   feature, check [Eyal's blog](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_s_hbm2ddl_tool), he
>   wrote a nice little entry about it.
>   Remember if you want to add additional
>   database objects (indexes, tables and
>   so on), you can also use the [auxiliary
>   database objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object) feature.

This should fulfill your needs.